# TextView overlapping tab on scrolling up

Tags: android, scrollview

I am facing some problems while developing a screen involving a tabWidget. I have used a scrollView. The problem is that when i scroll up, the editText overlaps the tabs. Here is my main.xml file. So when i try scrolling up, the title editText begins to overlap on the TabHeading.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    >
    <TabWidget android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        />
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="50px"
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        >
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/createAlarmTab"
                android:paddingTop="50px"
                >
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    />
                <EditText 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/desciption"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:lines="4"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    />
                <DatePicker
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/alarmDate"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    />
                <TimePicker 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/alarmTime"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/viewAlarmTab"
            android:paddingTop="50px"
            >
            <ListView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/alarmList"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:padding="10px"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it. Enclosed the scrollview inside a linearLayout and added some padding.